# what's the difference between lambda x : np.sqrt & lambda x : np.sqrt(x)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I encountered a problem:

```
df.apply(lambda x : np.sqrt)
```

I wonder why it hasn't any x for sqrt?

Answer (score 5):

This does not give the result you would expect. Instead of computing the square of each row value, it returns the function `np.sqrt` which is a constant python object.

To apply the square root to all elments of `df`, you should use:

```
df.apply(lambda x : np.sqrt(x))
```

or

```
df.apply(np.sqrt)
```

Actually, to obtain the same result, you can directly call `np.sqrt` on the dataframe since it is a vectorized function.

```
np.sqrt(df)
```

This would be the fastest way to compute the square root of all elements. You can read more [here](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/numpy/numpy-vectorization#:%7E:text=Numpy%20Vectorization%20with%20the%20numpy.&text=Numpy%20vectorize%20function%20takes%20in,element%20of%20the%20input%20sequence.) on numpy's vectorization functionality that maps a function over a sequence very efficiently.

Comment: or just `np.sqrt(df)`?

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang. Updated my answer to also provide this (faster) solution.